# Find common elements in list of lists

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list of lists of words called wordlist as follows:

```
[['dog', 'cat', 'sheep', 'rabbit', 'kiss', 'time'], ['cow', 'pig', 'bomb', 'cat', 'sheep', 'cake', 'boy', 'new']]
```

I want to find the common elements in all the sub-lists. Hence, my desired output of the above list should be:

```
['cat', 'sheep']
```

In order to achieve this, I created sets using the below code:

```
sets = set(tuple(row) for row in wordlist)
```

The set look like this:

```
{('cow', 'pig', 'bomb', 'cat', 'sheep', 'cake', 'boy', 'new'), ('dog', 'cat', 'sheep', 'rabbit', 'kiss', 'time')}
```

There can be any number of words per list, and there can be any number of lists. So I can end up with uneven sets of any number. I know I can compare two sets using the intersection methods, but how do I compare across multiple sets to return only the common items?

Answer (score 14):

You are using [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) incorrectly. You may use it like:

```
my_list = [['dog', 'cat', 'sheep', 'rabbit', 'kiss', 'time'], ['cow', 'pig', 'bomb', 'cat', 'sheep', 'cake', 'boy', 'new']]

# convert list of list to list of sets
my_sets = map(set, my_list)

# perform intersection on each set present in list
common_items = set.intersection(*my_sets)
```

This could be written in one line as:

```
common_items = set.intersection(*map(set, my_list))
```

The value hold by `common_items` will be:

```
{'sheep', 'cat'}
```

Here is the solution giving same result with the slightly **performance efficient approach**:

```
#                              v no need to type-cast sub-lists to `set` here
set(my_list[0]).intersection(*my_list[1:])

# OR,
# set(my_list[0]).intersection(*my_list)
# as intersection of set with itself returns the same set
```

Since `set.intersection` accepts all the iterables, there is no need to type-cast all the sub-lists to set.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use [*map()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map) to convert the inputs to sets, and then use [*set.intersection*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) to find their commonalities:

```
>>> data = [['dog', 'cat', 'sheep', 'rabbit', 'kiss', 'time'],
            ['cow', 'pig', 'bomb', 'cat', 'sheep', 'cake', 'boy', 'new']]
>>> set.intersection(*map(set, data))
{'sheep', 'cat'}
```